# Where do I put " require("firebase/firestore");" in my angular (4) application

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have searched the internet and read the Firestore documentation but cann't get started converting my part-built angular (4) project.

In the "Get Started with Cloud Firestore. I used npm to install firebase@4.5.1. Then the documentation goes on:

> "You'll need to manually require both Firebase and Cloud Firestore.

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");"
```

The problem is it does not tell you where it should go or how or if it needs importing.

A few days ago when I started this conversion I was able to

```
import * as firestore from 'firestore';
```

but now it says it cannot find it. I do not want to use angularfire, upgrading it after angular 4 was available was a nightmare.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this inside the component,

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
```

and in module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule, // imports firebase/firestore, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you, it turned out I was doing it right. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

After continuing my search I found I needed to

npm install --save @types/node

edit my Angular src/tsconfig.app.json file,

```
"types": [ "node" ],
"typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]
```

which took away the red underlines and it compiled.

Thank you Sajeetharan for spending the time to help me.